# Fastest way to compute dsitance between a list of pair of points

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have n points that are in k dimensional space (n by k matrix of data points). In addition, I have a list of pair of points that has length d (dimension of the list matrix is d by 2).

My goal is to find Euclidean distance between every pair of points of that list in a vector of length d.

What is the fastest way to do that in MATLAB for a long list? Do you think using C++/python might have a lot of speed-up?

Comment: It's not clear what you want, and how the two matrices are related. Can you give an example? Probably `pdist2` will be useful

Comment: More like pdist, but pdist give us an n by n matrix(distance between all pairs). What I want is just a few elements of that n by n matrix (whose index is in given to us) those few are two many, yet, they are very smaller than n(n-1)/2. Of course I can do it by a for loop, yet I was wondering if there is a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [22 44];
B= [44 66];
tic
distAB = sqrt((A(1)-B(1))^2+(A(2)-B(2))^2)
toc
distAB =

   31.1127

Elapsed time is 0.004398 seconds.
```

Well, MATLAB is pretty fast. Just make a for loop and update your points over time.

Your code should be something like this:

```
for i=1:length(d)-1
distAB(i)=sqrt((d(1,i+1)-d(1,i))^2+(d(2,i+1)-d(2,i))^2)
end
```